# Setting up a subscription with Stripe - Django-stripe-payments - Error TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up a Stripe monthly subscriptions using **django-stripe-payments**. I have followed the installation instruction and am still having problems.

I have added payments into the installed apps but i am getting TemplateDoesNotExist error

I have checked *.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/payments/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html* and the file is there! However the traceback says *File does not exist*

view.py

```
    @login_required
    def subscribe(request):
        form = PlanForm(request.POST or None)
        template = 'payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html' 
        context = {
        "form": form,
        } 
        return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r"^payments/", include("payments.urls")),
```

Traceback

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /subscriptions/subscribe
payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscriptions/subscribe
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html
Exception Location: /Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  /Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/nmninja',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 12 Mar 2015 22:34:56 +1100
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/nmninja/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html (File does not exist)
/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html (File does not exist)
/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_forms_bootstrap/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html (File does not exist)
/Users/andysair/Documents/personal/nmninja/lib/python2.7/site-packages/payments/templates/payments/templates/payments/_subscribe_form.html (File does not exist)
```

Comment: Do you have the app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable of your `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to putting 'payments' in your INSTALLED_APPS, adjust the {% extends "site_base.html" %} in the base.html file to your project's base.html file, i.e. replace site_base.html to your project's base.html file.